# BMW 320i Gearbox lubricant replacement

Tags: oil-change

I own a BMW 320i series 1997 model, ever since i bought it from its first owner i took it in for service two times but to my surprise the mechanic did not replace the gearbox lubricant/oil.

I would therefore like to know after how long should the gearbox fluid/oil be replaced and what are the indicators in that regard?

Answer (score 1):

Gearbox oil on modern cars can last a long time - tens of thousands of miles. You should be able to find a service schedule (it's usually in the back of the owner's handbook, which can often be found online) that will tell you how often it needs changing